# How to extract multi-word units from a column using R?

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

my data looks like this:

| Topic | Measure |
| --- | --- |
| climate change | reduce emissions |
| pandemic | vaccination |
| charity | call for donations |

Now I would like to extract all multi-word units (MWU) within one column, i.e.:

topic_mwu<-c("climate change")

measure_mwu<-c("reduce emission","call for donations")

Is there a function in R to extract these MWU automatically? Basically I only have to identify those entries including at least one whitespace, so I am thinking of an RegEx - hack..

I would very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work:

```
#your dataframe
dt <- matrix(c("reduce emission", "call for donations", "pandemic", "climate change", "donations", "charity"), ncol =2)

#make it a vector
dt <- as.vector(dt)

#if the table is very big, you can do unique() to remove duplicates
dt <- unique(dt)

#get the MWU
dt[unlist(lapply(strsplit(dt,split = " "), length)) > 1]
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Dear Rosalie, yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! 

Have a great day!
Best,
Mai

Comment: Great :) don't forget to validate the answer then, if you see this. Best, Rosalie